# Load first part after content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I want my website to load the first part not the entire page but when I give the scroll to load that part of the content.

```
|-------------------|
|   Navigation bar  | first part (width 100% and height: 750px;)
|        H1         |
|     Button        |
|___________________|

|-------------------|
| A lot of iframes  |
|    and images     | content (width: 100%)
|                   |
|-------------------|
```

The iframe :

```
<iframe src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4Qryoo5XFqEdUdEOE52amNiR1E/preview?usp=iframe_googleplus" id="iframe-pdf"></iframe>
```

**Like example :**

When you enter a site and scroll down, that site shows you how many people it has and the site calculates at that time or counts you at that time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read about  ->  [angularjs infinite scroll](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-infinite-scroll).
If scroll down u can detect it in callback and add anything to bottom of ur site